# Auto save each time Return pressed

Tags: vim

I need to save a line by line list of URLs in vim after each line.
Currently I need to use `:w` in insert mode (with <kbd>C-o</kbd>) or in normal mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd> and re-<kbd>i</kbd>)

Is it possible in vim to auto save after each <kbd>Return</kbd> ?

Answer (score 2):

This will do that:

```
:imap <Return> <Return><C-O>:w<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `vim`, just

```
cat >>url.list
```

and then paste the URLs into the terminal.  Then press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to end the input.

The `>>` redirection operator will make sure that the URLs are appended to the end of the file.